# Prevent a change being animated

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, uiviewanimation

Basically I changed the title of the navigation bar and then I want to animate the background color being changed. The code of doing so:

```
navigationItem.titleView = nil
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Unfortunately this will animate the change of the title as well. I want the title change to be immediate and then animate the change of the background. Currently I've fixed it with adding a delay function:

```
func delay(delay: Double, closure: () -> Void) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

But isn't there a more subtle way of doing so, instead having to add a delay?

EDIT:

Thanks thanks to the answer of Joshua Pozzi I changed it, but it's still not working.

```
let transition = CATransition(); transition.duration = 0.5

CATransaction.begin()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: .Default)

CATransaction.setDisabledActions()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem.title = ""

CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score -1):

See `CATransaction.setDisableTransactions()`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed and tried it but it's still animating along with the other animation.

Comment: The code you posted in your edit is not quite using the method I mentioned in my answer...

Comment: Sorry, I was testing different things out and copy pasted the wrong one. Edited the question now, still doesn't work. Hmm now that I check again, I was using `setDisabledActions`. Time for more digging :p

Comment: Sorry - I was giving the OS X answer; `setDisableActions()` is the correct method. The problem, I think, is the order of your calls. You want one transaction with actions disabled for your text change; the rest can be (but don't have to be) in their own transaction.